# What should replace a space in a api url?

Tags: urls, username, api

I am creating an **API**, where we can make reference to the users with their **firstname** and **lastname**. Since I can't use space, what is the best way to separate the firstname and lastname in the **url**? 
I was thinking about using underscore, like this:
http://example.com/api/user/firstname_lastname
Any better suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. As long as you are consistent people won't mind.

Comment: Are these URLs ones that users will browse to, or are they only to be used by API clients? In the latter case, will any humans ever see them?

Comment: Just wondering, you are "creating an API" (which is an application programming interface, if I understand this abbreviation correctly)..? I was hoping every API was completely covered by a UI (user interface) before some non-programmer saw it... :-|

Comment: @DanHulme, Humans will see the URLS after clicking on a link. I want the url yo be simple, so they can switch to another page just by changing the name at the end of the url.

Comment: @virtualnobi, It will (be completely covered by a UI), but once the url is visible, I want the users to understand that they can easily change page just by changing the url, without having to go back to the UI if they don't want to.

Comment: Sticking to the way in which GET data works it would be +

Comment: If the URL is visible, it's not really an API. I suggest you modify the wording of your question in order to make that clear. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @virtualnobi even if it is never covered by a UI and is only used by humans when they're writing software calling the API, it still has a user experience, and that can still be improved. CLI programs have a UX, and so do APIs, and for that matter, so do toasters and bridges. If a human is using it to fulfil some task, it has a UX, even if it doesn't have a UI.

Comment: Related:  http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 6):

Generally sites use either underscore or dash to replace a space in the URL. Underscore may be better because some persons have a dash in their name.

Consistency is also important. Don't use dash sometimes and underscore other times.

Comment: You won't come around changing name spellings. I don't know if having `O'Brien' in a URL is possible; re-converting it for inclusion into the URL after sanitation is probably too much trouble to be worth it. Most sites will probably come up with a schema to replace most nonword characters in names with something else when used in an URL, so why not dashes too.

Comment: I've provided a reason why underscores are better than dashes. Dashes aren't a bad choice, for the reasons you mention.

Answer (score 4):

If you really wanted to keep the space, you could [HTML Encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) it.

The result would be: http://domain.com/api/user/firstname%20lastname

Then all you'd have to do is HTML Decode it and you have your complete name.

---

@AndrewLeach's comment got me thinking, you might need to use a combination of `+` and `%20`.  A first and/or last name could have spaces in and of itself. For example, Bobby Ray Johnson Jr.  You'd have a space in between Bobby Ray and between Johnson and Jr.

The result would be: http://domain.com/api/user/bobby%20ray+johnson%20jr

Doing it this way, a developer could HTML Decode the whole name and then split on the `+` creating an array of two strings, firstname and lastname, which would already have the spaces retained.

Comment: But this won't be easy to understand for non-programmers

Comment: @SimonArnold - True, but who are the ones that use APIs? Developers, right?

Comment: A plus should also work: `http://domain.com/api/user/firstname+lastname`, which is arguably more understandable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Very true.  I like that format too.  I was just leaving an answer that shows how you can leave the space.

Answer (score 3):

If your api is RESTful or even RESTlike can't you just seperate them out into their own fields?

That way, you'd seperate them out with a "/" character the same way you seperate out the user field and everything else in your api.

This approach is the current convention in web api design.

i.e.:

```
http://domain.com/api/user/firstname/lastname
```

Comment: I like this one, though I'd probably reverse the name order to lastname/firstname. It seems to fit the hierarchy of paths better somehow.

Comment: @André so you put the last name first and the first name last?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: in a context like this, yes. Just like you'd find them in a phone book, by the way.

Comment: @André If you do it that way round, you imply a relationship between people that have the same last name, even if they're not connected. Since they're in the same folder. It makes sense to me to have a folder of all "Johns" distinguished by their last names, it makes less sense to have a folder of all "Smiths" if those people are not actually part of the same family.

Answer (score 3):

Your question made me join UX! UI is one of my biggest pet peeves of programming. And in the 20+ years I have been writing code, the single most consistent problem.

The question doesn't give me enough context to weigh in too heavily about the technology you are using or are allowed but I'm assuming the platform includes Windows.

The best I have seen presented thus far is `domain.com/name/name`

**Character encoding** is definitely going to bite you somewhere [as it did me](https://serverfault.com/questions/375381/how-can-i-check-if-php-was-compiled-with-the-unicode-version-of-the-win32-api/398523#398523). My application to import customer records and information into Quickbooks has mangled names for a decade and I never got to the bottom of it until the most recent go at it when a few records would refuse to import. I go on a lot about this below...

**Allow for name changing.** I have some customers who gave us their name 4 or 5 different ways, and that doesn't include the Pat/Patrick like cases. We are keying everyone on their email addresses, which isn't perfect but about the best we could come up with. IMHO, force people with an OpenId or Google login. The Google is in everyone's lives and only a few are completely without a Google account.

**`Last, First - zip`** is what we ended up deciding upon for our Quickbooks "customer name" and I do lots of work around eliminating any spaces outside of the `" - "` separator. Then as we encounter a customer that moved or name is different, we change that account's name to `Last, First - OLD` and may or may not later go back and merge the customers (historically requires Single User mode). Of all the things we tried, this best helps telephone support with Quickbooks as the operator's sole tool. With our web app, we can search on anything.

---

### Spend more time on input validation & handling

**Spaces in URLs** are handled almost automagically, so to me this is the least of your worries. Worry about the space people and work more extra hours for handling these. There are `McDonalds` and `Mc Donalds` type entries from my customers. And `van Name` or `Name von Name` customers too.

**First/Last ordering** doesn't matter really, so long as that customer is consistent. You can specify Last/First and anyone currently in China or Korea will always flip those.

**Always strip leading and trailing spaces.** *I know about this* and still find I often enter my name on forms as `Chris_` and `Kelley`.

**Never discount `E. E. Cummings`** type names, they're about as frequent as `O'Brians` but less consistent. There are also people who use their middle name, like `E. Fred Johnson`.

Ultimately, take whatever the user types and do your best to come up with a rule. If you do magic with their input at least warn them what their login is and/or give them approval or choices:

> Hi E. Fred,
>
> Your login is based on your name and we want to make sure you use the
>   login the same way you use and type your name in everyday life; please
>   pick the option you wish to have as your login. Don't worry, you can
>   change it later, too:
>  ✔ <kbd>Fred</kbd>
>  ☐ <kbd>E.
>   Fred</kbd>
>  ☐ <kbd>E Fred</kbd>
>  ☐ <kbd>EFred</kbd>

**O'Brians** are prevalent and also come as:
`O'Brian` <sub>typed on my US keyboard</sub>
`O´Brian` <sub>with acute accent U+00B4</sub> <sub>([This is a great link for the quotes](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html))</sub>
`O’Brian` <sub>with U+2019 directed closing single quote</sub>
`` O`Brian `` <sub>with grave accent U+0060</sub>
`O Brian` and `OBrian` happens when customers have already been punished by technology for their name.

When it comes to the single quotes, the next time I'm programming the front end on a web app (hopefully never again), I'll detect for all single quotes not `' from us keyboard` and then make a whole special dialog for handling this and reminding the user about that symbol possibly not being found on keyboards in other countries and then force them to the `' from us keyboard` and/or putting in effort to see if their keyboard can type those.

**Accented characters:** As a very user-sympathetic programmer, I hate to say it but my recommendation is to be ethnocentric and drop tilde **`ñ`** and umlat **`Ö`** accented characters, as I described in [my Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/375381/how-can-i-check-if-php-was-compiled-with-the-unicode-version-of-the-win32-api/398523#398523). The discussion about how to handle these might be as expansive as the rest of my rant/missive above. To be the most polite, you can store their UTF-8 encoded original entry and use it for comparison and/or display elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Per [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) your candidate characters are

```
$-_.+!*'(),
```

I'd choose "+".

```
http://domain.com/api/user/firstname+lastname
```

Encoders used the "+" character as a replacement for a space character in the early days, and many still do, though I think the official spec calls for using %20 now. I think dot, dash, and underscore have aesthetic value too.

A note of caution: if you permit names that use UTF-8 characters, you have to encode them, losing their aesthetic. See [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> Non-ASCII characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8 [STD63],
> and then each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence must be
> percent- encoded to be represented as URI characters.  URI producing
> applications must not use percent-encoding in host unless it is used
> to represent a UTF-8 character sequence.

Comment: The only issue with doing it this way is that if your firstname and/or lastname had spaces in it, then you'd have multiple `+` occurrences. How would the code know which part belongs with which name?  Look at the 2nd part of my answer for a solution to that.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Essentially all escapable (including non-ASCII) characters are subject to this. I think the OP has to figure out what kind of cake he should make if he wants to eat it too.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work properly, underscore `_` is the language independent (ASCII) character to use. The dash (which I love to use) doesn't match in all character encoding languages.

I've implemented a `string.replace()` of no less than seven different dashes imported from XML to a product database. I don't want seven different products depending on dash character encoding. That's why underscore is correct.

But also, this depends on context. If you want to signal different words, and don't care which dash of dashes it is, use dash.

> If you use an underscore '_' character, then Google will combine the two words on either side into one word. So bla.com/kw1_kw2.html wouldn't show up by itself for kw1 or kw2. You'd have to search for kw1_kw2 as a query term to bring up that page.

And Jeff Atwood wrote in his article [Of Spaces, Underscores and Dashes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes.html) that:

> As you can see (on character in different languages), the dash is not matched, but underscore is. This_is_a_single_word, but this-is-multiple-words.
>
> Like NutraSweet and Splenda, neither is really an acceptable substitute for a space, but we might as well follow the established convention instead of inventing our own.

## To Conclude

If your not sure, and are in the context of programming - use underscore! If you want to signal different words (to Google Analytics as one example) use dash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a period character, it's a little less chunky looking than an underscore.

Comment: But what if I have to make a reference to someone like J.K. Rowling?

Comment: Why is the perceived chunkiness of the separator a factor here?

Comment: @SimonArnold Isn't it supposed to be a first name or a middle name? J.K. is not a first name.

Comment: Yes, but I'm worried about people who have multiple firstname or uncommun firstname that everybody shorten. Like who know who is Joanne Rowling? But everyone know who is J.K. Rowling, right?

Comment: Could you expand on this answer please? As it stands, it does not really explain where the cluncky-ness comes from, or who is perceiving it this way. As it stands, this answer is a candidate for removal.

Comment: For the sake of our dear moderators - underscores are not used in natural written English.  They're easily confused with dashes.  With a period, nobody's going to ever confuse "dot" or "period" if hearing a URL (as in in conversation) and it also doesn't require use of the shift key to type.  So that's the "clunky".  But the "chunky" is the visual part.  A period... gets right to the point.